# Sleep function not working after program is saved

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a time.sleep function to have my strings printed letter by letter, and it works perfectly while running inside pycharm, yet when I save the program and run it directly, the function does not take effect

```
def welcome():
     greeting = random.choice(open_msg)
     for i in range(len(greeting)):
            print(greeting[i], end='')
            time.sleep(0.15)
```

This is an example of what the code looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Python's output is line-buffered. Therefore it won't print anything until you print a linefeed. To avoid this behavior, flush the output after each letter. Since Python 3.3, `print()` has an argument to do this. (For older versions, you need to `sys.stdout.flush()` after each `print()`.)

```
print(greeting[i], end='', flush=True)
```

You can cause Python not to buffer by invoking it with the `-u` flag or by setting the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` to any value. But these affect all output. It's better to use `flush` where you need it and leave other output buffered, because buffered is faster.

By the way, don't use `range()` when iterating over a string. Iterate over the string directly and you get the characters.

```
for c in greeting:
    print(c, end='', flush=True)
    # etc.
```

Comment: Tried this and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Ides can take longer to execute, amplifying the time.sleep() function
Maybe lengthen the time in the argument of time.sleep()

Answer (score -3):

It should be working. Perhaps you forgot one of your imports? If so, here is the code, it is written well.

```
import random
import time
open_msg = ['hello', 'finished', 'chicken']
def welcome():
    greeting = random.choice(open_msg)
    for i in range(len(greeting)):
        print(greeting[i], end='' )
        time.sleep(0.15)
welcome()
``
```

Comment: It only "should be working" (where "working" is understood to mean "printing one character at a time") if stdout is completely unbuffered. That's not true by default even when stdout is a TTY -- stdout is by default line-buffered when it goes to a TTY, or fully buffered (flushed in much larger blocks) otherwise.